# gnuradio add code to file_sink

Tags: sliding-window, gnuradio, usrp

I want to store data from an USRP1 with a file sink. But I need some more logic, i.e. I don't want to store all the data but only some "events" (changes which exceed some threshold). For that I want to use a sliding window and store only the the specific vectors. Does anyone knows where I can add this code?

Thanks,
Tino

Answer (score 0):

Answered this on [discuss-gnuradio](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-06/index.html):

> Then don't put the logic into the file sink -- use, for example, the
>   squelch block in a setting that doesn't let samples through as long a
>   certain threshold hasn't been crossed for a configurable period of
>   time -- or write that block yourself, it's not too hard if you read a
>   bit up on stream tags; have you met the guided tutorials?